# Cannot set/get value from cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have a very simple page with the following logic:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (null == Response.Cookies["UserSettings"].Value)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
        cookie.Value = "The Big C";
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
    else
    {
       // got here
    }
}
```

I set a breakpoint in both the `if` and the `else` and the `else` break point never gets hit.  The `if` statement gets hit every time.  What could be wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Do both the Request.Cookies and Response.Cookies have the same values?  I think they do, but could double check that Request.Cookies gives you the cookie back maybe?

Comment: Request gives the correct value (The Big C).  Should I use Request instead of Response to read the cookie?

Comment: Sure... Response will not give you cookies as it is still being created in the very next line...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you checking `Response.Cookies` you should be checking `Request.Cookies`. response is still being created..

**Update**

See, When you **add** a cookie by using the **HttpResponse.Cookies** collection, the cookie is immediately **available** in the HttpRequest.Cookies collection, even if the response has not been sent to the client. **But** you are checking for the cookie in the Collection **even before its added**. So yu need to check for it in Request.Cookie Collection